# wget only downloads a url into index.html, how to show the content of index.html?

Tags: wget

I am trying to use wget to get the content of of a particular url.
wget [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

it only downloads a index.html. I want to see the content of the html to show as a result of
wget [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

is there a way to do that using wget? I know I can use curl to get it but unfortnately, curl is not available to use.

Please advise. thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

*want to see the content of the html to show as a result of wget [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)*

If you want to get content to standard output then do:

```
wget -q -O - https://www.example.com
```

`-q` (*quiet*) does turn off Wget's output, `-O -` is write to standard output. If you want to know more read [wget man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).